# How to determine the color of the one part of the text in cell by Apache POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I have Excel table.
In the cell we can have text (`for example text1;text2`) and part 1 (`text1`) of this text will have black color,
but another one (`text2`) have, for example, red color.
For read Excel file I use Apache POI.

Could you please ask how to determine the color (`which in our case is red`) of THAT second part of the text.

For determination of the whole text in the cell I use now this code:

```
      HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (HSSFCellStyle) currentCell.getCellStyle();
        short cellColor = cellStyle.getFont(currentCell.getSheet().getWorkbook()).getColor();
```

I don't know if it determinate it correct

Comment: You'll need to fetch it as a [RichTextString](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString.html), then work your way along that fetching the formatting of each chunk. Did you try that? How far did you get?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried to work with RichTextString but I didn't understand how to get color of the part. `HSSFRichTextString richTextString = (HSSFRichTextString) currentCell.getRichStringCellValue();`                                                  see the methods for apply certain font to the part of the string, but how to get it ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to fetch the cell's contents as a [RichTextString](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString.html) and then get the formatting information from that

For HSSF, your code would want to be something like:

```
HSSFRichTextString richTextString = hssfCell.getRichStringCellValue();
for (int i=0; i<richTextString.0,r.numFormattingRuns(); i++) {
    if (richTextString.getFontAtIndex(i) == HSSFRichTextString.NO_FONT) {
        // Default cell formatting rules apply to this bit
    } else {
        HSSFFont font = workbook.getFontAt(richTextString.getFontAtIndex(i));
        // This bit of the string has the above font
    }
}
```

You can use methods like [getIndexOfFormattingRun()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRichTextString.html#getIndexOfFormattingRun%28int%29) to work out where in the string the font changes